# What am I describing

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.
>   The next three times I hover or drag.
>   In, the very end, I'm still not out.
>   Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

Hint 1:

> I'm hard to get a hold of, but easy to find
>  Look in an abandoned corner and find me there

Hint 2:

> I, both a letter and myself

Comment: Fingernails or earwax or boogers or eye boogers? A brother of gristle and hair

Comment: Is this in a similar format of a Riley Riddle? Also, @Duck, finger nails don't really sneak around... but the riddle could be metaphorical :)

Comment: @user477343 hmm almost, there are one or two diffrences.

Comment: The comma in the first sentence looks like a possible grammar mistake, but could also be very intentional. Which one is it? The same is true for the first comma in the third line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> [Spidroin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spidroin)

At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.

> Spy, but with "I" instead of "why" = "spi"

The next three times I hover or drag.

> three letters from (drag and) drop = "dro"

In, the very end, I'm still not out.

> not out = "in"

Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

> All three are proteins

Hint: *I'm hard to get a hold of, but easy to find*
*Look in an abandoned corner and find me there*

> Spidroin is found in spiders' webs

Hint: *I, both a letter and myself*

> Refers to the "I" on the first line

Comment: Hazzah! someone got it! Some stuff on the hints: Whfg gb avgcvpx oebgure gb tevfgyr naq unve ersref gb vg orvat n fpyrebcebgrva yvxr pnegvyntr naq xrengva. Nyfb V jnf guvax "qebar" nf ubire be qent, ohg V thrff lbhef jbexf gbb.

Answer (score 11):

The answer must be

> KERATIN.

*At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.*

> It looks like this means KEY (useful when sneaking around?) minus Y ("why"), giving **KE**. Thanks @MOehm for the tip here.

*The next three times I hover or drag.*

> **RAT** - perhaps because it's like a mouse and computer mice are used to hover or drag?

*In, the very end, I'm still not out.*

> This literally means **IN**.

*Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.*

> Keratin is a type of body tissue which is related to gristle and hair.

Comment: (KE + "why" is KEY, but I don't see how that refers to sneaking. And hovering and dragging is what you do with a computer mouse, but I've never heard one referred to as RAT. Yeah, I got nothing ...)

Comment: @MOehm Thanks! Incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: You're so very close but I'm slightly more exotic.

Comment: Also it might be helpful for you to know that keratin is *not* a body tissue but actually a protein that makes up hair.

Comment: I would also like to pose the question; is it rot13(erfcbafvoyr sbe gur perngvba bs tevfgyr)? My interpretation is that it isn't, as rot13(tevfgyr vf glcvpnyyl sbezrq ivn glcr VV pbyyntra). Either way, +1 from me, this was a great answer.

Comment: @PerpetualJ you're a step closer, in that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> an [eyefloater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater)?

At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.

> they sneak around your vision and noone really understands what they are and why they appear sometimes (except those who read the wikipedia article)

The next three times I hover or drag.

> trying to blink or moving the  eye doesnt help, they just hover to another place in your vision

In, the very end, I'm still not out.

> there is no real technique to get them out

Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

> it looks like hair. (don't know what it has to do with gristle)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> cobwebs / spider silk / fibroin?

At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.

> Spiders are sneaky

The next three times I hover or drag.

> No idea about the 3 times, but spiders hover and drag silk around as they spin webs

In, the very end, I'm still not out.

> Spider silk comes out of a spider's spinneret, which is on its "end" - but as it comes out, it's still attached

Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

> Fibroin is a scleroprotein like cartilage (gristle) and keratin (hair)

Hint 1 part A:

> **I'm hard to get a hold of, but easy to find** - maybe it's easy to find cobwebs but they tend to be in places that're hard to actually reach/touch

Hint 1 part B:

> **Look in an abandoned corner and find me there** - cobwebs for sure match this

Comment: Closest yet. You're on the right track but think more riley.

Answer (score 0):

Wild throw here,

> snot, though this ain't exotic

At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.

> most of the time you don't notice your snot because it's doing its job up there undisturbed.

The next three times I hover or drag.

> Don't know why three would be specially important, but snot can hang out of your nose and if you wipe it like a 5-year-old you drag it across your face instead of getting rid of it.

In, the very end, I'm still not out.

> sometimes that snot just won't come out.

Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

> another type of bodily item

I'm hard to get a hold of, but easy to find
Look in an abandoned corner and find me there

> used tissue left on the floor?

Notes:

> I definitely follow suit that it is some sort of gross thing created and left behind by the human body. The only things I can think of left in the carpet are all nasty things :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, but along the lines of *Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair*:

> Skin

Another thought was along the lines of:

> Epidermis

Since you stated you're looking for something more exotic. I'm still looking, and if either are the answer then great! If not, then maybe I can find it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> Corneocyte (component of dust)?

At first I sneak around but I, don't ask why.

> uh, idk...

The next three times I hover or drag.

> dust hovers in air

In, the very end, I'm still not out.

> Skin cells at the end of your epidermis are still stuck to you?

Overall, I'm a brother to gristle and hair.

> Corneocytes are related to cartilage and keratin

Hint 1 A:

> **I'm hard to get a hold of, but easy to find** - dust floating in air is easy to find, but you can't just grab it

Hint 1 B:

> **Look in an abandoned corner and find me there** - Corneocytes are a major component of indoor dust

Hint 2:

> **I, both a letter and myself** - corneo sounds like cornea - part of the eye

RE comments:

> Also, being the very outer layer of the epidermis, this would definitely be exotic in a literal sense.

Comment: RE: hint 2 - I'm pretty sure it's this or something to do with rot13(fpyren - cneg bs gur rlr, nyfb pybfr gb fpyrebcebgrva (juvpu pnegvyntr naq xrengva ner))